# Kendo grid reordering row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-sortable

I have a kendo grid inside kendo grid (using integrated grid). I have implemented drag n drop in both grid using grid sortable provided by kendo. But it is only work with one grid at a time. If I commented one of them, second grid reordering perfectly. I want that user can able to drag n drop both grid. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing filter option in parent grid.

var grid = mygrid.data("kendoGrid");
                grid.table.kendoSortable({

```
                handler: ".handler",
                **filter: ">tbody >tr:not(.k-detail-row)",**
                hint: function (element) { //customize the hint
                    var grid = $("#gridProductGroup").data("kendoGrid"),
                        table = grid.table.clone(), //clone Grid's table
                        wrapperWidth = grid.wrapper.width(), //get Grid's width
                        wrapper = $("<div class='k-grid k-widget'></div>").width(wrapperWidth),
                        hint;

                    table.find("thead").remove(); //remove Grid's header from the hint
                    table.find("tbody").empty(); //remove the existing rows from the hint
                    table.wrap(wrapper); //wrap the table
                    table.append(element.clone()); //append the dragged element
                    //table.append(element.next().clone());
                    hint = table.parent(); //get the wrapper

                    return hint; //return the hint element
                },
```

Filter differentiate  between detail grid and parent grid.
It is working for me